# EF Core Fluent API to map collection of Users

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have a Notification class

```
public class Notification
{
    public int NotificationId { get; set; }

    public string NotificationMessage { get; set; }
    public DateTime NotificationSentOn { get; set; }

    //TODO: not sure how to map this in fluent api
    // a Notification can go to many users
    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> ReceivingUsers { get; set; }
}
```

and the extension of ApplicationUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        IsAuthor = false;
    }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisteredDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsAuthor { get; set; }

    // foreign key to UserProfile using the string ID from ApplicationUser
    public UserProfile MemberProfile { get; set; }
    // collection of notifications for this user
    public ICollection<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the error relating to the Notifications property in the ApplicationUser class

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'ApplicationUser.Notifications' of type 'ICollection'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

I believe the relationship should be one-many , i.e. one Notification goes to many ApplicationUsers, but my normal pattern in Entity
Configuration doesn't work, I must be missing something in one of the classes.

I am not sure how to map both the Notifications collection or the foreignkey relation to UserProfile using the fluent API ( I am using EntityConfiguration classes using IEntityTypeConfiguration interface)

**Update**
Per Camilo's answer, I updated my Entity Configurations to include the NavigationUser table setting the primary key as follows

```
public class NotificationUserEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<NotificationUser>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<NotificationUser> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(u => new { u.ApplicationUserId, u.NotificationId })
            .HasName("PK_NotificationUser");

        builder.Property(u => u.NotificationId)
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .IsRequired();            

        builder.Property(u => u.ApplicationUserId)
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .IsRequired();

    }
}
```

This returned the following from the db creation script

It created a ForeignKey in the ApplicationUser table

```
table.ForeignKey(                        name: "FK_AspNetUsers_Notifications_NotificationId",
        column: x => x.NotificationId,
        principalSchema: "MachineryCtx",
        principalTable: "Notifications",
        principalColumn: "NotificationId",
        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
```

and a ForeignKey in the NotificationUsers table back to notifications

```
table.ForeignKey(                       name: "FK_NotificationUser_Notifications_NotificationId",
      column: x => x.NotificationId,
      principalSchema: "MachineryCtx",
      principalTable: "Notifications",
      principalColumn: "NotificationId",
      onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to model a many-to-many relationship as if it were a one-to-many.

You should have something like this instead:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    ...
    public ICollection<NotificationUser> Notifications { get; set; }
}

public class Notification
{
    ...
    public ICollection<NotificationUser> Users { get; set; }
}

public class NotificationUser
{
    public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public int NotificationId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public Notification Notification { get; set; }
}
```

That says:

- A user can have many notifications
- A notification can have many users

You can either have an `IDENTITY` Primary Key or a Composite Primary Key with `ApplicationUserId,NotificationId`

Comment: ...and NotificationUser becomes a join table in the db? or it is unmapped?

Comment: @dinotom You need the join table in the db. It's the only logical way to map a many-to-many

Comment: It wont migrate that way...."The entity type 'NotificationUser' requires a primary key to be defined." .

Comment: @dinotom Agh, migrations, useless technology... post updated :)

Comment: ...Happy Holidays, since you took the time to respond today. See my update, the two foreignkeys are created but it just doesn't look right. But heck, what do I know, I have the problem. If it is right I will accept your answer. I'm just not grasping how this gets me a collection of either.

Comment: @dinotom No, it doesn't look right at all, because many-to-many relationships are illogical, so we need to work around 2 one-to-many to overcome this. But, that's what we have